# Need with a momentum and impulse physics question on image below 6.3

Tags: physics, newtons-method, bulletphysics, vimpulse, conservation-laws

[grade 12 momentum -physics questions need assisance with 6.3][1]

How to calculate the final velocity of a body given two graphs of two objects of net force versus time
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7UZq.jpg

Comment: 1. Welcome to Stack Overflow. 2. Please look at our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help); this question is unacceptable. 3. The problem (or the part that you have shown us) does not provide enough information to determine the answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is appears to be a homework problem with no sign of effort toward a solution.

Comment: I have attempted this question with al means possible ..have tried to use the conservation of momentum , or create simultaneous equations of impulse before and after collision ..i assumed there is a collison since Fnet changes direction for object Q

Comment: This is a high school question but i went further to try and integate to get velocity as a function of time to know use

Comment: Conservation of momentum doesn't help, because we know nothing about the thing imparting a force on the object. We can calculate the momentum imparted to the object, but without knowing the *mass* of the object, we cannot calculate the acceleration. And even if we knew the change in velocity, we do not know the initial velocity, so we cannot calculate the final velocity.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a physics question, not a programming question. Check out [the physics stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 6.1 you have calculated the total impulse p for Q.
To get from impulse to velocity you can use the definition of impulse: p = mv.
Therefore you need the mass m of the object Q, which seems not be given.
With the data given the answer would be:

final velocity = v = 60 / m
in m/s